# How to change Mapbox Polyline decoding precision to 5?

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox, osrm, mapbox-android

As I know Mapbox SDK (RouteUtils.java) uses precision of 6 to decode polyline and that affects Mapbox Navigation. When passing `DiresctionsRoute` with precision 6 to `startNavigation(directionsRoute)` every navigation listener works perfectly. But when adding `DirectionsRoute` with precision of 5 (as it's default precision from OSRM.V5). No listener works properly. How could I solve the problem.

> NOTE: We're using OSRM.V5 in our server so it always returns route
>   with precision of 5. And we aren't intended to use Mapbox's
>   `getRoute()` as it's restricted at some point fro free users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `geometries=polyline6` option in OSRM, but it requires 5.8.0 version

Example http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?overview=simplified&geometries=polyline6

API reference http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.7.0/api/#route-service